# Redirect Flask Stadout to Guinicorn log file

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, gunicorn

Would someone please let me know how to send flask standout to guinicorn logs.

Following is my code

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    print "print statement"
    return "<h1>hello World</h1>"
```

**Gunicorn Command**

```
gunicorn test:app -b 0.0.0.0:5005 --access-logfile ./access.log --error-logfile error.log --log-file gunicorn.log --capture-output -R --reload
```

However I am able to **stdout** in **gunicorn.log** only after I shutdown my application.

```
[2018-12-03 11:27:39 -0500] [68235] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2018-12-03 11:27:39 -0500] [68235] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5005 (68235)
[2018-12-03 11:27:39 -0500] [68235] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-12-03 11:27:39 -0500] [68238] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 68238
[2018-12-03 11:29:13 -0500] [68235] [INFO] Handling signal: int
[2018-12-03 11:29:14 -0500] [68238] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 68238)
print statement
print statement
print statement
[2018-12-03 11:29:14 -0500] [68235] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `print` use `app.logger.info(<expr>)`

Comment: I know how to redirect the logs. And I am able to redirect `stdout` as well. the only issue is, it's getting appened only after I close the app.